# SAS proc freq of multiple tables into a single one

Tags: database, group-by, sas, dataset

I have the following dataset in SAS;

```
City  grade1  grade2  grade3
NY      A.      A.      A
CA.     B.      A.      C
CO.     A.      B.      B
```

I would "combine" the three variables grades and get a proc freq that tells me the number of grades for each City; the expected output should therefore be:

```
     A.    B.   C
NY   3.    0.   0
CA.  1.    1.   1 
CO.  1.    2.   0
```

How could I do that in SAS?

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few steps but it gives the expected result.

```
*-- Creating sample data --*;
data have;
infile datalines delimiter="|";
input City $ grade1 $ grade2 $ grade3 $;
datalines;
NY|A|A|A
CA|B|A|C
CO|A|B|B
;

*-- Sorting in order to use the transpose procedure --*;
proc sort data=have; by city; quit;

*-- Transposing from wide to tall format --*;
proc transpose data=have out=stage1(rename=(col1=grade) drop= _name_);
by city;
var grade:;
run;

*-- Assigning a value to 1 for each record for later sum --*;
data stage2;
set stage1;
val = 1;
run;

*-- Tabulate to create val_sum --*;
ods exclude all; *turn off default tabulate print;
proc tabulate data=stage2 out=stage3;
class city grade;
var val;
table city,grade*sum=''*val='';
run;
ods select all; *turn on;

*-- Transpose back using val_sum --*;
proc transpose data=stage3 out=stage4(drop=_name_);
by city;
id grade;
var val_sum;
run;

*-- Replace missing values by 0 to achieve desired output --*;
proc stdize data=stage4 out=want reponly missing=0;run;
```

```
City  A B C
 CA   1 1 1
 CO   1 2 0
 NY   3 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In general:

- Transpose data to a long format
- Use PROC FREQ with the SPARSE option to generate the counts
- Save the output from PROC FREQ to a data set
- Transpose the output from PROC FREQ to the desired output format

```
*create sample data;
data have;
input City $  grade1 $ grade2 $ grade3 $;
cards;
NY     A      A      A
CA     B      A      C
CO     A      B      B
;;;;


*sort;
proc sort data=have; by City;run;

*transpose to long format;
proc transpose data=have out=want1 prefix=Grade;
by City;
var grade1-grade3;
run;


*displayed output and counts;
proc freq data=want1;
table City*Grade1 / sparse out=freq norow nopercent nocol;
run;

*output table in desird format;
proc transpose data=freq out=want2;
by city;
id Grade1;
var count;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it in two steps: a sort step and a data step.

```
proc sort data=have; by city; run;
data count (drop grade1-grade3);
    set have;
     * create an array of all your grades;
    array grade(3) 3 grade1-grade3;
    by city;
     *set the count to zero for each city;
    if first.city then do;
        A = 0;
        B = 0;
        C = 0;
    end;
    * use a do loop to count the grades;
    do i = 1 to 3;
        if grade(i) = 'A' then A + 1;
        else if grade(i) = 'B' then B + 1;
        else if grade(i) = 'C' then C + 1;
    end;
run;
```